# RequireJS Ajax being called too much

Tags: javascript, ajax, requirejs

Running on a rails server, when I make an ajax call by submitting the form, the form goes through 3 times. This picture shows 3 failed but whether they fail or succeed, they are run 3 times.
[image]

When I take away:

```
require(['/assets/monitor/monitor'], function(Monitor){
    var monitor = new Monitor();
    monitor.initial();
});
```

it stops working completely. When I take away only:

```
var monitor = new Monitor();
monitor.initial();
```

it makes 1 ajax call.

Why is the ajax still being called when I am not calling an instance of the monitor file?

main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './',
    paths: {
        'jquery': '/assets/monitor/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        'jquery-ui': '/assets/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min',
        'async': '/assets/monitor/lib/async',
        'bootstrap': '/assets/monitor/lib/bootstrap',
        'underscore': '/assets/monitor/lib/underscore',
        'datatables': '/assets/monitor/lib/jquery.dataTables.min',
        'DT_bootstrap': '/assets/monitor/lib/DT_bootstrap'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
            'async': {
                exports:'async'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
                deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'datatables': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'DT_bootstrap': {
            deps: ['datatables']
        }
    }
});
require(['/assets/monitor/monitor'], function(Monitor){
    var monitor = new Monitor();
    monitor.initial();
});
```

monitor.js

```
define(['jquery', 'async', 'bootstrap'], function($, async, jQuery) {

    var Monitor = function() {};
    // Kicks off the file
    Monitor.prototype.initial = function () {
        var hostname = 'http://somehostthatworks';
        var portNumber = 'some port that works';
        var contentType = 'JSON';
        var versionNumber = '1.1';
        this.receiveMonitor(hostname, portNumber, contentType, versionNumber);
    };
    ...
    Monitor.prototype.recieveMonitor = function(hostname, portNumber, contentType, versionNumber) {
        $("form").submit(function () {
           //Some ajax that works when form is submitted.
        });
    };
    ...
});
```

application.js

```
// Call requireJS and main.js
//= require ./monitor/lib/require
//= require ./monitor/main
```

Answer (score 0):

By moving the calls for require.js and main.js out of application.js and into the page that I needed them (well call is monitor.html.erb), I was able to stop the duplication.

monitor.html.erb

```
...
<% @stylesheetIncludes= ["bootstrap.min", "jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min", "monitor", "jquery.dataTables.min"] %>
<% @javascriptIncludes= ["monitor/lib/require", "monitor/main"] %>
<!-- Monitor Service -->
<%= render 'monitor/monitorService' %>
...
```